# Passing pointer to function as an output parameter

Tags: c++, pointers

I am using 'pBuff' as pointer and put a char array in function 'myfunc'.
So, In main function, I should receive it in aBuff.

But it is not working.. what is wrong here ??

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myfunc(void *pBuff, int &i);
int main()
{
    int len;
    char aBuff[2]={0};
    printf("Hello World");
    myfunc(aBuff,len);
    printf("aBuff %s", aBuff);

    return 0;
}

myfunc(void *pBuff, int &i){
    char a[2] = {'a', 'b'};
    i = 5;
    pBuff = &a;
}
```

`char a[]` should come as output parameter in main function

Comment: I don;t think you can, after all, you're trying to return a local array from the function.

Comment: But , I am passing the address of ```a```. Or  how can i get ```char a[]``` back ?

Comment: `what is wrong here ??` You are taking the reference (&a) to a temporary which is destroyed after myfunc returns... and why exactly is pBuff a void pointer?

Comment: Why is this question C++ tagged and not C?

Comment: It is working by using double pointer. ```void myfunc(void **pBuff, int &i);```

Comment: If you've made no other changes it's only working by chance, you're invoking undefined behaviour

Comment: Thank you everyone for their answers and effort. I will try to understand it from starting. Thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return an array you have several possible solutions:

1. Pass a pointer (`type*`) to the function and copy the data unsing e.g. `memcpy`. You should also pass the size of the destination array and make sure you don't copy too much data.
2. Pass a reference to the pointer (`type *&`) and assign to the pointer in the function
3. Pass the address of the pointer (`type**`) and assign the address to the dereferenced pointer.

You must not return the address of a local variable with automatic storage. If you want to return `a` (which is a pointer to the first element) from the function it must be either `static` or dynamically allocated using e.g. `malloc`.

Which solution to choose depends on your needs:
Examples for 3 variants:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

void myfunc(char **pBuff, int &i);
void myfunc2(char *&pBuff, int &i);
void myfunc1(char *pBuff, size_t bufsize, int &i);

int main()
{
    int len;
    char aBuff[3]={0}; // increased size for NUL termination
    char *ptr = aBuff;
    printf("Hello World");
    myfunc(&ptr,len);
    printf("ptr %s", ptr);

    printf("\n");
    myfunc2(ptr,len);
    printf("ptr %s", ptr);

    printf("\n");
    myfunc1(aBuff, sizeof aBuff,len);
    printf("aBuff %s", aBuff);

    return 0;
}

void myfunc1(char *pBuff, size_t bufsize, int &i){
    char a[3] = {'c', 'd', '\0'}; /* added '\0' to allow using it as a string */
    i = 5;
    // actually the minimum of bufsize and sizeof(a) should be used
    memcpy(pBuff, a, bufsize);
}

void myfunc(char **pBuff, int &i){
    static char a[3] = {'a', 'b', '\0'}; // added '\0' to allow using it as a string
    i = 5;
    *pBuff = a;
}

void myfunc2(char *&pBuff, int &i){
    static char a[] = "xyz";
    i = 5;
    pBuff = a;
}
```

Comment: -1: 1) `aBuff` has size 2, but myfunc/myfunc2 put in 3 chars -> stackoverflow. 2) unsing static is just bad advice. 3) pointer to pointer or reference to pointer is not necessary here, it actually results in aBuff beeing not used after myFunc or myFunc2 is called, at all.

Comment: @user1810087 `myfunc` and `myfunc2` don't overwrite `aBuff` but assign a new address to ptr. Whether returning a `static` buffer is bad or not depends on the requirements which are not clear here. Of course a function cannot modify `aBuff` by assigning a pointer.

Comment: `myfunc and myfunc2 don't overwrite aBuff but assign a new address to ptr` - Exactly, making aBuff as a **buffer** pretty pointless. `a static buffer is bad or not depends on the requirements` - true, but in most cases it is unnecessary. In general I (and I think some other people too) would say, static should be used very rarely and with care. Consider, whenever you call myfunc **you the user of this function** provide a buffer, which is not used! Instead a static (global/shared) buffer for **all** caller to myfunc is used! That's bad. Even worse, myfunc1/myfunc2 use different static buffers.

Comment: After your edit: myfunc1 seems to go into the right direction. But still the static is missleading. Some cleanup and proper bounds checking would still be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a pointer to your function, inside your function you assign the address of the temporary variable `a` to the `pBuff` variable. The original `aBuff` variable is unaffected.

As we are using c++ a much simpler solution using strings would be:

```
#include <iostream>

void myfunc(std::string& pBuff, int &i);
int main()
{
    int len;
    std::string aBuff;
    std::cout << "Hello World";
    myfunc(aBuff,len);
    std::cout << "aBuff " << aBuff;

    return 0;
}

void myfunc(std::string& pBuff, int &i){
    pBuff = "ab";
    i = 5;
}
```

If you really must use raw character arrays then this would be one way to implement it (note the removal of the `void*`, no reason to use it here):

```
myfunc(char *pBuff, int &i){
    strcpy(pBuff, "ab");
    i = 5;
}
```

If you need to store 2 characters in your `aBuff` array it needs to be 3 characters long not 2 as you need to leave space for the null terminator otherwise `printf` and other string functions will not work correctly.